# java.lang.RuntimeException: PARAGRAPH span must start at paragraph boundary (46 follows )

Tags: java, android, html, textview, spannablestring

I am getting the below error While trying to Render the Text in the Text view

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: PARAGRAPH span must start at paragraph boundary (46 follows  )
                                                                   at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:161)
                                                                   at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.copySpans(SpannableStringInternal.java:67)
                                                                   at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.<init>(SpannableStringInternal.java:42)
                                                                   at android.text.SpannedString.<init>(SpannedString.java:30)
                                                                   at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod.getTransformation(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:83)
                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4436)
                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4332)
                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4307)
```

I am calling like

```
myAsyncTask().execute(source, listDrawable, textView.getContext());
                    return listDrawable;
                }
            }, new MyTagHandler());
      textView.setText(htmlText);
```

Can anyone Help me in this to sort the above issue

Comment: Can https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview/issues/6 help you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably using the function [`Html.fromHtml(String source)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)), which has been changed for `Android SDK API >= 24 (Anrdroid 7.0)`, to get your Spannable for `textView.setText(htmlText)`, so the resulting Spannable now differs a bit. Because of that, it won't fit to old deprecated functions/attributes anymore.

Therefore, you have three options to solve your problem:

- (**EDIT:**) Probably the easiest solution: If you are using the android attribute `android:singleLine=true` in your list element use `android:maxLines="1"` instead.
- Basically, you have to take care of your Spannables and their bounderies, especially if you're creating your Spannables by yourself.
- Use only supported HTML tags, which can be read out directly from the source code ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java#791)).
- You can also use the function [`loadDataWithBaseURL(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to resolve your problem, but then you have to use a webview, which could be a big overload for a list element.

Comment: I'm using custom spannable so based on your second point how do I change boundaries ?